# How can I get more information when debugging a contract violation that checks for equality

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, eiffel

I have the following Eiffel code. I am doing test-driven-design with contracts.

```
check
    sorter.sorted (<<1>>).is_equal (<<1>>)
end
```

The code correctly detects that my sort returns the wrong value. However it would be nice to see what `sorted` returned. I can see that it is too late as `is_equals` consumes both values, and returns false, before the check throws the exception.

I have seen in other testing frameworks they have a special `is_equal` for the test framework. That allows better feedback. e.g.

`check_equal(expected, value_under_test)`

Is there anything like this in eiffel?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at library `testing`. In particular, class `EQA_COMMONLY_USED_ASSERTIONS` has feature `assert_equal` that seems to do what you want to:

```
assert_equal (a_tag: READABLE_STRING_GENERAL; expected, actual: detachable ANY)
        -- Check that `expected ~ actual'.
```

The original example would then look like

```
assert_equal ("Is array sorted?", sorter.sorted (<<1>>), <<1>>)
```

Comment: Yes I think it should work, unfortunately I can't get it to work. All sorts of errors with compatibility of concurrency of library and project. Every time I try to fix I just get another error. So it must be time to ask another question. But today I need a rest.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Please, tell the version number of your Eiffel compiler and concurrency settings of your project.

Comment: It is the latest, downloaded a few days ago (`Version = EiffelStudio 19.5 (19.05.10.3187 GPL Edition - linux-x86-64)`).  The concurrency settings are SCOOP, I do not need them for what I am doing, so decided to set it to None. Bit this just creates other compile errors. Saying the precomp is not compatible. I can't work out how to resolve.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor A quick solution would be to remove the precompile from your project (in the Project settings navigate to Target | Groups | Precompile and remove the nested node). Then you would need to [recompile the project from scratch](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffelstudio/Clean_compile).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Does it answer your question? If yes, it makes sense to mark the answer as accepted, if not, further questions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `check` statements are *not* "debug" statements:
`check` statements are to ensure the correctness (i.e. trigger on errors), while debug statements help to understand what's going on.
To debug your code once a `check` failed, you would add `debug` statements that output information *before* the `check` triggers.